# Appcode - Select Current File

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, appcode

In Xcode I can press Shift-Cmd-J to select the current file on the left.

Is there a shortcut that does the same in Appcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest equivalent (as far as I know) is the "Select in..." command. The standard shortcut is <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, but you can change that in the Keymap settings.

It requires an additional <kbd>⏎</kbd> to select the current file in the project navigator (you can also reveal it in the Finder or structure view this way), so it isn't *exactly* the same.

Comment: This works only if I hold down Fn as well. A bit awkward

Comment: @GauravSharma that's because on Macs the F keys are "disabled" by default to leave the media keys there. You can change this around in system preferences so that you can press the F-keys by default and then the Fn key enables the media buttons.

Comment: I've simply mapped this to Cmd+Shift+J, that's already so deep in my muscle memory...

Answer (score 2):

`⌥-F1` then press `ENTER` will do this for you.

It will just bring up a menu but by hitting enter you are selecting the default option.

There is an app I use called cheat sheet which is handy for this kind of thing.

[Cheat Sheet](http://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/) - hold down ⌘ and it shows all keyboard shortcuts for the app you're currently in.